# Facebook login in Chrome extension, permissions

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension I need to have the Facebook token available all the time. To get this, I check for token by opening a tab and then querying the token from the hash:

```
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, tab) {
    if (tab.url && tab.url.indexOf(redirect) === 0) {
      var params = tab.url.match(
        /access_token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&expires_in=([0-9]+)/
      );
```

Here, "redirect" is a Facebook url.

To get this working I need *"tabs"* permission, which renders as *"Access your tabs and browsing activity"*, which may be repulsing for some users.

So is there a way to get Facebook token inside the extension with minimum amount of permissions and as seamlessly as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could issue an XMLHttpRequest to Facebook, which would require facebook to be listed in the permissions. Alternatively, you could have your own website/backend that you authenticate with Facebook, and then you could have your extension list your website, instead, and have your website do the interaction with Facebook.

Comment: Thanks, authenticating through my own website seems like the best solution.